# task scheduler to run in Apache Felix?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I want to implement a task scheduler to run in Apache Felix. The idea is the task scheduler will read a crontab file, and execute the task (the task is defined by a installed services or bundles) periodically. What is the best way to do this? I am new to OSGI, and good suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's not really an OSGi matter (OSGi doesn't cover crontab-type event scheduling), I'd say use a 3rd party open source scheduler like Quartz:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

However, it's not an OSGi bundle out of the box, so that still might require some effort to make it work.

Other suggestion: Apache Sling seems to have a built in scheduler (also based on Quartz), and as Sling is OSGi based, it should be reasonably easy to add to your app.

http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html

Hope this helps, Frank

Comment: The apache Sling look like what I need, thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it more.